# how to retrieve post_id under woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation hook?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I am trying to retrieve post id under custom_fields_validation() function but I am receiving the following

> error: Trying to get property of non-object on line 116

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation','custom_fields_validation'), 10, 3 );



public static function custom_fields_validation() 
    { 

    global $post;

if(isRecurring($post->ID)){
if ( empty( $_POST['inputday']) ){
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select field 1;', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            return false; 
        }
        if ( empty( $_POST['inputtime'] )){
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select field 2;', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            return false; 
        }
}           
    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` passes the product id as the second argument to the callback function, so you can access it like this:

```
function custom_fields_validation( $passed_validation, $product_id ) { 
    if( isRecurring( $product_id ) ) {
        if ( empty( $_POST['inputday']) ){
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select field 1;', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            return false; 
        }
        if ( empty( $_POST['inputtime'] )){
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select field 2;', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            return false; 
        }
    }

    return $passed_validation;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_fields_validation', 10, 2 );
```

Also, note that `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` is a filter, not an action, so I've used `apply_filters` instead of `add_action`. I also fixed a syntax error, where you had an extra parentheses after `'custom_fields_validation'`.

I also updated the function to return the current validation state. Otherwise you could be returning `true` even if a previous validation had failed.